# return value from loop

Tags: ruby, loops, each

I have a hash `@hsh={a:1,b:2}`
 and want to return a port 
but it returns to me `{a:1,b2}`

```
  def my_def(port)
   @hsh.each do |k,v|
      if v == port
       port = k
      end
    end
  end
```

My problem is when i doing  `my_def(2)` it do not returns me `'b'` and i

got whole hash back `=>{a:1,b:2}`

Comment: That is not a hash. It is invalid.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Replace `port = k` with `return k`?

Comment: @sawa my question is how to return value  from loop if coincidence found

Comment: @xxx and haven't ndn already answered your problem?

Comment: To return the key for a given value, use `@hsh.key(2) #=> :b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return a value from a loop, use `break value`:

```
def my_def(port)
  @hsh.each do |k, v|
    break k if v == port
  end
end
```

In general, @Stefan’s comment solves this *particular* problem better:

```
def my_def port
  @hsh.key port
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning a value from `each` isn't idiomatic Ruby. Better to use `find`, `select` etc. Or just:

```
{a:1, b:2}.invert[2] # => 'b'
```